# Why does logRequest not log requests?

Tags: logging, spray

According to the [documentation](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/debugging-directives/logRequest/), Spray allows user to log request and response.

However, for some reasons, I can't seem to make it work.

Here's what I have on the "routing side"

```
def generateRoute = pathPrefix("session") {
 logRequest("session reached") {
  path("new") {
    logRequest("session new reached") {
      post { entity(as[Initiate]) { sessionInfo =>
        logRequest("session new post reached") {
            complete("pass\n")
          }
        }
 /// the rest of the braces
```

Here's what I have in my configuration:

```
akka {
  loglevel = DEBUG
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
}
```

Here's what I see in my log:

```
app 11/29 13:02:35 DEBUG[sys-tracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] a.i.TcpListener - New connection accepted
app 11/29 13:02:36 DEBUG[sys-tracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] s.c.s.HttpServerConnection - Dispatching POST request to http://localhost:8080/session/new to handler Actor[akka://sys-tracker/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/1#2086889080]
app 11/29 13:02:36 DEBUG[sys-tracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] s.c.s.HttpServerConnection - Connection was PeerClosed, awaiting TcpConnection termination...
app 11/29 13:02:36 DEBUG[sys-tracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] s.c.s.HttpServerConnection - TcpConnection terminated, stopping
```

So, even though I have logRequest directives in my route, the request is not logged. Any ideas why?

Comment: Probably your `logRequest` was never reached because your `pathPrefix` never matched. Note that pathPrefix requires a Slash and then its argument ("session" in your case). So if the unmatched portion of the URI path was not `/session` then it won't match and the request won't get logged.

Comment: No, the path is matched. I tested it thru curl and got 'pass' response

Comment: How about your `logback.xml`? Maybe you are filtering out the logging there?  The default log level for `logRequest` is DEBUG.

Answer (score 8):

I have built a sample solution with spray-routing and just your route function and configuration. I do see log statements corresponding to your logRequest methods. The output includes both text passed to logRequest and HttpRequest.

```
01:42:36.946 [SprayRoutingExample-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] DEBUG akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl - session new post reached: HttpRequest(POST,http://localhost:8080/session/new,List(Accept-Language: en-US, en, Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, Accept: */*, Content-Type: text/plain, Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo, User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36, Content-Length: 4, Connection: keep-alive, Host: localhost:8080),HttpEntity(text/plain,test),HTTP/1.1)
```

Try changing the log level for your call to see if that makes any difference

```
logRequest("session reached", akka.event.Logging.InfoLevel)
```

What do you use as concrete logger implementation. Check that your logger configuration is correct. I used logback.

Comment: Mind showing the logger configuration to complement the answer?

Comment: Changing the log level for the call is what got it to work for me